# Question about curves and Puiseux series

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves

Let $f\in\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ be an irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ polynomial such that $f(0,0)=0$. I'm trying to understand the uses of Puiseaux series $y(x)$ in the variable $x$ to solve the equation $f(x,y)=0$ i.e. to find points in the curve $X=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{C}:f(x,y)=0\}$.  My question is that is it true that it can be done globally, more precise, i.e. are Puiseaux series $y_1,\dots,y_n$ such that

$$f(x,y)=(y-y_1(x))\dots(y-y_n(x))\tag{$\star$}$$

for all $(x,y)\in X$  (independently of this point being a singularity of the curve or not)? If not, what are the requirements on the point $(x,y)\in X$ so that the decomposition $(\star)$ holds.

Comment: Yes $\bigcup_{n\ge 1}\Bbb{C}((x^{1/n}))$ is algebraically closed.

Comment: ($\star$) will hold, like reuns says, but evaluating $y_1$ at $x$ might not make sense for two reasons: 1) for example, the Puiseux series $x^{1/2}$ is not a function (unless you choose a particular square root for every $x\in \mathbb C$).

Comment: The equality $(*)$ holds algebraically. However, the Puiseux series appearing on the RHS may not ve evaluated in complex points. There is a theorem saying that the pusieux series that arrise from solutions to a polynomial as yours have positive radius of convergence

Comment: And 2) even if $y_1(x)$ has no fractional powers, it might not converge for a given $x$. For example, solving $(y+1)^2=x+1$ makes $y_1(x) = -1+\sqrt{1+x}$ and $y_2(x)=-1-\sqrt{1+x}$, neither of which converge for all $x$

Comment: But note that this is what one expects, since the zero set of $f$ is an analytic subvariety and therefore you usually study them locally. To take care of the problem of choosing square roots, it is better to work with multivalued functions

Comment: @AitorIribarLopez could you give me a reference for the theorem that guarantees the convergence in a neighborhood of the point

Comment: @user34870 google TAsty Bitsw of Several Complex Variables and, in the pdf, look for the word Puiseux